# Semantic Search technique 3

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I want to build a semantic search with elasticsearch for example, if we search with the term "sport" it returns "football" ...
 something that understands the intent of the user, is there any database of synonyms or topics, categories, related term ... could help doing that.

Comment: Get the basics searching the web, then show some code that you tried to get running.

Comment: I'm beginner in this I don't know where I start

Comment: What results did you get searching the web? What books or articles have you read?

Comment: I read a lot, but just definitions of the meaning of semantic I didn't find ways to do it with elastic.

Comment: Check http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=football&i=3&h=1000000#c